# what is a role of leader epoch checkpoint in log segment of Kafka partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

what is a role of leader epoch checkpoint in log segment of Kafka partition?

[image: folder capture image]

Answer (score 21):

In Kafka, a [*leader epoch*](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/ba237c5d21abb8b63c5edf53517654a214157582/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/epoch/LeaderEpochFileCache.scala#L42) refers to the number of leaders previously assigned by the controller. Every time a leader fails, the controller selects the new leader, increments the current "leader epoch" by 1, and shares the *leader epoch* with all replicas. The replicas use the *leader epoch* as a means of verifying the current leader. If a leader fails and returns, when it tries to contact other replicas, it will send what it believes is the current *leader epoch*. The replicas will ignore the messages sent with outdated *leader epochs*.

The *leader-epoch-checkpoint* file contains two columns: epochs and offsets, as shown [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/ba237c5d21abb8b63c5edf53517654a214157582/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/checkpoints/LeaderEpochCheckpointFile.scala#L43). Each row is a checkpoint for the latest recorded *leader epoch* and the leader's latest offset upon becoming leader. Both replicas and leaders contain this file. Its role is for checking what range of offsets pertain to which epoch.

Comment: There is also a good explanation in [KIP-101](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-101+-+Alter+Replication+Protocol+to+use+Leader+Epoch+rather+than+High+Watermark+for+Truncation)